# My laptop's inbuilt keyboard is not working

Tags: drivers, keyboard, hardware, hardware-test

I have a acer aspire one D250 laptop. I had accidentally dropped it on the floor then the keyboard stopped working. Then I used it with a USB keyboard for couple of months. It had windows xp before the accident then I installed Ubuntu 16 and used it with USB keyboard but I wasn't comfortable with it so I bought a new replacement keyboard but it is also not working.

Is it something related to device drivers?
I have already replaced it with 2 replacement keyboard and this is the 3rd one which I have bought

can anyone help?

PS: the motherboard got damaged

Comment: If the keyboard does not work while you are attempting to get to BIOS, then it is certainly a hardware problem.

Comment: So if I replace it with new keyboard it still doesn't work

Comment: I would make the assumption that the keyboard itself is OK, but the connectors may be broken, or perhaps some traces on the botherboard.

Comment: How do I check the motherboard

Comment: The connector on the motherboard seems to be fine